# Why model/variable keeps its value?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have problem with my code in Laravel Framework. What I am trying to do is sell method inside model. The problem is that $variable keeps its value untill next code execution. How I should make it so it's gonna work like I want to?

```
/// Model method.
public  function Sell()
{
    $this->UserData->increment('gold', ($this->ItemData->price / 100) * 80);
    $this->delete();   
    return null;
 }


 ///in controller 
 $user = \Auth::user();
 $user_item = UserItems::find(10);
 $user_item->Sell();

 return $user_item->ItemData->name; /// Returns full data about model even if I deleted it/sold. After next refresh, returns null/error.I want it to return null since beginning.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question misses some important information. It is not clear why name should change.

Comment: Hey, as @GordonFreeman says, it would be really helpful for you to provide more detail on your goals and what you have tried so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you have deleted a record from a database by `$this->delete()`, `$user_item` variable still holds a reference to the filled model until the script ends or you destroy the variable.

It seems that you want to return a result of the `sell()` function. In your case it would be

```
///in controller 
$user = \Auth::user();
$user_item = UserItems::find(10);
$user_item->Sell();

return $user_item->Sell();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do but below code will solve your issue -

```
/// Model method.
public  function Sell()
{
    $this->UserData->increment('gold', ($this->ItemData->price / 100) * 80);
    $this->delete();
    $this->ItemData = $this->ItemData->fresh() 
    return null;
 }


 ///in controller 
 $user = \Auth::user();
 $user_item = UserItems::find(10);
 $user_item->Sell();

 return $user_item->ItemData->name; /// Returns full data about model even if I deleted it/sold. After next refresh, returns null/error.I want it to return null since beginning.
```

Comment: There is a better way to retrieve a fresh instance. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models `$model->fresh()` or `$model->refresh()`